# Is there an editor which allows you to design UI like Xcode for Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic3, webstorm

I am starting out with Ionic and I been using VSCode for all my development. One thing I miss in VSCode is the ability to view the UI (not as HTML) like preview and able to change things in the preview screens (like Visual Studio for asp.net).

Does VSCode do that with any plugins or is there an alternative editor which has this feature?

Comment: *"VS Code doesn't have built-in support for HTML preview but there are extensions available in the VS Code Marketplace. Open the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X) and search on 'live preview' or 'html preview' to see a list of available HTML preview extensions.*"  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html

Answer (score 0):

After some research found this https://creator.ionic.io  and Robert Harvey's answer is good answer.